# Are custom-written grouped UITableViews really the way to implement standard forms on iOS?

Tags: ios, forms, uitableview, interface-builder, formsets

## What is this about

I notice many many apps I use have a similar way of implementing form (sets). For example:

[image]
[image]

This is basically the same scheme used in the Settings app as well.

## My problem

When I need to make something like this, I basically make a grouped `UITableView`, define how many groups with how many fields each I have, etc. The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` basically becomes a big switch statement which sets the right form field as `accesoryView`. I make all the form fields in advance in the code and make sure they are set up properly.

However, I have this feeling that there must be a much better way. This feels like an awful lot of repetitive code. And code which I find very difficult to make pretty.

## What I want

Ideally, I'd just like to write my form completely from Interface Builder, because it's really intuitive for me. So creating a `UITableView` and it-s content in Interface Builder. Just making a form in IB is simple of course, but not while also putting the fields in a grouped tableview - which I do really want because it looks pretty and consistent.

Another option is something like the [Settings bundles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html): I define the type and name of my fields, the code of the app renders the table, creates the field instances, etc.

I'm in search of something better because it seems quite odd to me that such a extremely common problem needs to be handled in such a complex way. Especially considering that so many of the common problems are already handled well. But on this problem, I can't find anything.

So: is my approach really the best way of displaying these kind of forms? Can parts be improved? Is there any way I've overlooked for the existing iOS libraries to help me?

Comment: I have been searching for something to fill this void for ages,  completely agree Erik there must be a better way... perhaps www.inappsettingskit.com is a good start...

Comment: I also just ran into: https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog which seems like a nice way to handle this for forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UITableView` really is the best way to go. You could use a `UIScrollView`, but that will involve a lot more work since you lose out on the built in functions that `UITableView` offers.

If you prefer to use the IB, which I completely understand, then you can create each `UITableViewCell` in the IB, lay it out with objects, link up an `IBOutlet`, and then include it that way into your `UITableView`. This also makes it easy to set up actions and delegates for the objects you're using, e.g. `UITextField`s and `UISwitch`es.

Comment: Almost 6 years later... is this still as good as it gets for designing an input form? A newer option I see is stack view, but it still feels like a lot of boilerplate work, setting up dividers for example.